# DBMS to use for failover

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, postgresql, database-replication

We are developing a payment system for venues.
Now we're considering what DBMS to use for our application.
At the moment we're using microsoft's sql express to store our data.
But because the system is going to be used on very busy venues, we think we need a failover system for the case the database server goes down.
We have been looking at using mssql server for replication, but that is going to cost a lot of money for a case that is (hopefully) never going to happen.
The database has to be up for only a couple of hours (duration of venue) to max a couple of days.
But if the database is down for 30 minutes, noone can order drinks or get access to the venue. And with thousands of people in the venue, thats going to cause a lot of trouble.

So... can anyone share some of his expretise and/or share some reads for me about failovers, replication or anything?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you forget about the DBMS until you have a clear business plan, systems architecture and defined goals for availability. Ideally, find someone who has implemented a system like this before and hire them or use them as a consultant.

You also have to look into how much money you will lose if the system goes down: actual sales, loss of reputation and future business, contractual penalty clauses etc. Compared to those costs, adding a second server might start looking fairly cheap. But where will they be hosted, how does connectivity work, who does Operations etc.? Having a fully redundant failover database cluster will not help you if your one and only Wifi base station for the POS terminals suddenly dies.

Perhaps you have already considered and answered all these questions, and if so it would be helpful to add some more details to your question about the main constraints and requirements you have.

Comment: Well the project is as good as finished. But here development doesn't go like it normally should... at the moment one of the cash registers is hosting the database, but what we want to do is put the database on a different machine, maybe a laptop, and if the venue is bigger maybe on 2 or more laptops with replication or failover.